# How to create SQL query to get unique values of column for each GROUP'ed BY value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

First of all I'm sorry for confusing name of my question, I didn't know how to ask it correctly.

I will show the example of what I'm trying to do. Let's imagine we have 3 tables: 'footballer', 'team' and 'score' in a database (I'm using MySQL 5.5 as DBMS). They are very straightforward:

```
CREATE TABLE footballer (
  fb_pk      INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name CHAR(40),
  last_name  CHAR(40),
  PRIMARY KEY (fb_pk)
);

CREATE TABLE team (
  team_pk INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name    CHAR(40),
  PRIMARY KEY (team_pk)
);

CREATE TABLE score (
  score_pk      INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  goal_count    INT(3) NOT NULL,
  team_fk       INT(8) NOT NULL,
  fb_fk         INT(8) NOT NULL,
  goal_distance ENUM('LONG', 'SHORT'),
  PRIMARY KEY (score_pk),
  CONSTRAINT fk_team FOREIGN KEY (team_fk) REFERENCES team (team_pk),
  CONSTRAINT fk_footballer FOREIGN KEY (fb_fk) REFERENCES footballer (fb_pk)
);
```

'score' table stores information about goals made by teams & football players, where:

'goal_count' - is a number of goals made,

'team_fk' - is a foreign key for the team,

'fb_fk' - is a foreign key for a footballer and

'goal_distance' - is a type of goal(s) were made (long or short).

We have the following data in the tables:

```
INSERT INTO footballer (first_name, last_name)
VALUES
  ('Footballer', 'One'),
  ('Footballer', 'Two'),
  ('Footballer', 'Three'),
  ('Footballer', 'Four'),
  ('Footballer', 'Five');

INSERT INTO team (name)
VALUES
  ('Team 1'),
  ('Team 2'),
  ('Team 3');

INSERT INTO score (goal_count, team_fk, fb_fk, goal_distance)
VALUES
  (2, 1, 1, 'SHORT'), -- Two goals | by team #1 | by player #1 | short goal
  (3, 1, 1, 'LONG'),
  (1, 1, 2, 'SHORT'),
  (1, 2, 1, 'SHORT'),
  (2, 2, 2, 'SHORT'),
  (2, 2, 4, 'LONG');
```

Row **(2, 1, 1, 'SHORT')** means that 2 short goals were made by player 1 from team 1.

Now I want to collect the statistics data for the 'score' table: how much short / long / total goals were made by each team and **how much players within the each team made the goals**. Here is my query with comments:

```
SELECT
  -- Team name
  t.name,
  -- How much short goals
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(s1.goal_count)
    FROM score s1
    WHERE s1.team_fk = s.team_fk AND s1.goal_distance = 'SHORT'
  ) short_count,
  -- How much long goals
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(s1.goal_count)
    FROM score s1
    WHERE s1.team_fk = s.team_fk AND s1.goal_distance = 'LONG'
  ) long_count,
  -- Total goals
  (SELECT short_count + long_count) total,
  -- How much players made goals
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        team_fk, fb_fk
      FROM score
    ) s1
    WHERE s1.team_fk = s.team_fk
  ) goal_player_count
FROM score s
INNER JOIN team t
  ON s.team_fk = t.team_pk
GROUP BY s.team_fk;
```

Query returns the following result:
[image: result]

It works as expected, but I think there is a better way to get the count of '**players within the each team that made the goals**'.

To become more clear how this value must be calculated, here is an example:

There are 3 rows in a 'score' table for team #1:

```
(2, 1, 1, 'SHORT'),
(3, 1, 1, 'LONG'),
(1, 1, 2, 'SHORT'),
```

Player 1 made 2 short goals,

Player 1 made 3 long goals,

Player 2 made 1 short goal.

In total, there are **2** players who made goals for this team (Player 1 and Player 2).

Currently, this peace of query is responsible for calculating that value:

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        team_fk, fb_fk
      FROM score
    ) s1
    WHERE s1.team_fk = s.team_fk
) goal_player_count
```

Maybe there is another (better) way to achieve the same result? Because this part of query looks ugly/unusual for me (SELECT inside the SELECT inside the SELECT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the information you want in a much smaller query:

```
  SELECT t.name,
         SUM((s.goal_distance = 'SHORT') * s.goal_count) short_count,
         SUM((s.goal_distance = 'LONG')  * s.goal_count) long_count,
         SUM(s.goal_count) total,
         COUNT(DISTINCT f.fb_pk) goal_player_count
    FROM team t
    JOIN score s
      ON s.team_fk = t.team_pk
    JOIN footballer f
      ON f.fb_pk = s.fb_fk
GROUP BY t.team_pk
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f676/5)

This makes use of the fact that in MySQL a comparison, e.g. `s.goal_distance = 'SHORT'` will return `0` for false or `1` for true (or `NULL`) thus allowing counting under different conditions. Also the `DISTINCT` option for `COUNT()` is useful in this case.

I am surprised that you chose not to record each goal in a separate tuple. This would allow individual stats, such as the time of the goal, to be recorded without much additional workload to this query and would allow for much more flexible reporting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer a lot. I found very useful for me example of expression within the SUM function which is transforming into 1 or 0 depending on data. But the most useful part for me is COUNT (DISTINCT ...) construction which I learned from your answer (never saw before). That's something I was feeling lack of in my query.

Comment: About the design of my tables. 

I faced the problem that is described in my question while working with another DB schema. But the tables I am working with are too big and complecated to post them here.

So I imagined another more straightforward example to reproduce the problem I met. Of course, in the real world the design of my schema would be different :)